# How to retrieve the value at a given index?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am fairly new to programming and I am working on a project that involves shifting nodes. How can I get a node at a particular position denoted by user input and increase its value by one? To better explain:

here is my code...or my attempt:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};
class LinkedList {
private:
    Node* head;
public:
    LinkedList() 
    {
      head = NULL;
    }


    void print()   
    {
        Node* current = head;
       if (head != nullptr)
       {
        do 
         {
           std::cout << current->data << " ";
           current = current->next;
         }
        while (current != head);
       }
    }
};

int main() 
{
  LinkedList link_one;
  int nodes;
  std::cout << "nodes ";
  std::cin >> nodes;
  for (int index = 0; index < nodes; index++){
    link_one.print();
  }
  link_one.print();
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: *"How can I get a node at a particular position denoted by user input and increase its value by one?"* -- pick one operation to ask about. Can you get a node at a particular position (hardcode a position for the sake of testing and don't make all the values the same)? Can you get a position denoted by the user (no list implementation required)? If you were given a node (the first node might be useful for testing), could you increase its value by one? Which specific task are you having trouble with?

Comment: Perhaps, you've complicated my question a bit? I happen to think that the question is specific enough. A user picks an index and the value at that index is retrieved, then increased...I'm happy to answer any questions - but I believe that it is specific enough.

Comment: *"A user picks an index and the value at that index is retrieved, then increased"* -- right, there are three steps. A Stack Overflow question should be focused on one step. That makes the question useful to more people in the future, and it is conducive to using a simpler, easier-to-read [mre]. (Based on the answer you accepted, you should have focused on retrieving the value at a given index.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try traverse

actually there is no need to write a answer, but...I am a newcomer :)

your function place_node should add a parameter:

```
int place_node(int idx)
```

then...traverse from your head node for "idx" times, modify the value of current node, that's it.

here's the complete code for function place_node to achieve your goal:

```
int place_node(int idx) //no need to return
{
  Node* current = head;
  int count, index = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<idx;++i) current = current->next;
  current->data+=1;
  return 1; // no need to return
}
```